# Fixed width sidebar with responsive main div in bootstrap 2.3.2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, fluid-layout, twitter-bootstrap-2

Im trying to get a fixed width side bar with a responsive main div when using bootstrap 2.3.2.

Something like this image below

[image: fixed sidebar, fluid main div]

Ived tried to use a `200px` fixed width div and then place a fluid div next to it, but couldnt get it to work. Any ideas ? ive made a js fiddle of the problem here - http://jsfiddle.net/KAfMB/1/

Comment: Have you checked the [layouts](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#layouts)?

Comment: Yeah i had a look through those, and although they have a [fluid side bar layout](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#layouts) - it leaves both sections fluid rather than the sidebar fixed and main div fluid.

Comment: Is this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SqmZX/) What are you looking for?

Comment: @AdamZapp - Not really as the right hand side div dosnt seem to be fully responsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your "fixed-span" class is being overridden by the bootstrap span classes.
You can solve this removing the word "span" from your class:

```html
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="fixed blue cols">...</div>
    <div class="span8 red cols">...</div>
</div>
```

```
.fixed {
    width:200px;
    float: left;
}
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/KAfMB/4/

Comment: Thats pretty much it, do you know if theres a way to stop the layout breaking when the browser container goes bellow 510px - the red div drops below the blue one ?

Comment: You could define a min-width for that container.  Check out - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp